# Plot a graph in python using common values in dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, matplotlib, plot

How can I visually represent the common keys when a value is selected. I am creating a form where the user will select a value, say `'john'`. I want to plot  the common keys'a', 'b' and 'c'. Suggestions on how to approach this problem will be very helpful.

```
d = {
'a': ['john', 'doe', 'jane'], 
'b': ['james', 'danny', 'john'], 
'C':['john', 'scott', 'jane'],
}
```

Comment: You want to plot a count for `john`?

Comment: @JoeR Yes! visually show that 'john' is present in a, b and c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({
'a': ['john', 'doe', 'jane'], 
'b': ['james', 'danny', 'john'], 
'c':['john', 'scott', 'jane'],
})

#get boolean mask by condition
print (df == 'john')
       a      b      c
0   True  False   True
1  False  False  False
2  False   True  False

#sum values True
print ((df == 'john').sum())
a    1
b    1
c    1
dtype: int64

(df == 'john').sum().plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

If need show all data:

```
df1 = df.apply(pd.value_counts).T
print (df1)
   danny  doe  james  jane  john  scott
a    NaN  1.0    NaN   1.0   1.0    NaN
b    1.0  NaN    1.0   NaN   1.0    NaN
c    NaN  NaN    NaN   1.0   1.0    1.0

df1.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image: graph1]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a data frame from the dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

df = pd.DataFrame({
'a': ['john', 'doe', 'jane'], 
'b': ['james', 'danny', 'john'], 
'c':['john', 'scott', 'jane'],
})
```

Then you can simply plot `john` like this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: (x == 'john').sum()).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

*Since the string `john` only occurs one time in each column, all the bars are the same length.*